# Difference between walking and hiking?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Is there any difference between walking and hiking?

There is more popular tag [hiking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiking) and less popular [walking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/walking) (used intensively be me in past...). I see they are used for the same activity, so my question is, are they synonyms?

I'm not native speaker and I haven't actually used word 'hiking' (only in context hitch-hiking). So if they are generally meaning the same, they should be synonymized  to avoid further misunderstanding.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not a native speaker either, but I think there is a difference.

*Walking* is the process of moving on foot.  You walk to the supermarket or to work.  You walk through the park or though the city.

*Hiking* is the recreational activity.  It's usually done in nature, such as in the forest or in the mountains.  It can also be done in a city, but that's unusual.  my parents once walked 25 km through Paris on a single day; that probably classifies as hiking.

I'd say hiking is a subset of walking.  All hiking is walking, but not all walking is hiking.

I live in a town that has some steep slopes and some footpaths are actually quite stony trails.  My wife (not a native speaker) might complain (particularly in winter) that here, getting by in the city is not walking, but hiking.

Comment: Hmm, is 'hiking' something like German 'wandern'?

Comment: I'm less sure in German than I am in English.  I'd think *wandern* is *hiking*.  For *walking* I'd be tempted to say *laufen* but I'm not sure if it has exactly the same meaning.  (My native language is Dutch).

Comment: @ŁukaszLech Yes, hiking = wandern.

Comment: This leeds to the question if [tag:walking] is an outdoor activity and/or on topic here? Since its not recreational nor done by purpose but a mere way of transportation - like bus-riding...

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker, I believe Gerrit has is exactly right.

"Walking" is any time you move on foot.

"Hiking" is usually strenuous walking, done outdoors, for recreation.  For instance, if I drive out of the city and into the mountains and walk around all day long with a backpack and a water bottle: that is hiking.